# How to find the LCP of string pairs in a set

Tags: algorithms, strings, suffix-trees, longest-common-substring

I have a set of $k$ strings of $n$ length each. I need an algorithmic strategy that finds the **LCP** (Longest Common Prefix) of each set's string pair. In addition, I need time complexity $O(k*n+a)$, where $a$ must be the sum of all LCPs.

Any tip/paper/help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what "each set's string pair" means.  Do you mean the LCP of each pair of strings, i.e., $k(k-1)/2$ LCPs?

Comment: Can you tell us anything about the context where you encountered this?  Did you see it in some textbook or exercise?  If so, can you tell us more?  What's the best algorithm you've been able to find so far?  What approaches have you considered?  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Isn't it trivial to obtain $O(a)$ complexity by finding LCP individually for every pair of strings?